# LED bulbs flash once, turn off. Unscrew one and screw back in they all turn on?

Tags: ceiling-fan, led

Had a ceiling fan with cheap LED bulbs, they would flicker a lot and had an electrician tell me cheap bulbs can do that. So bought some GE and now when I turn it on they flash once. I’ll unscrew one and screw it back in and they all come on. They are 60 watt equivalent and candelabra bases.[image]

Comment: What make and model is the fan, and what turns the lights on and off?

Comment: A light switch. No dimmer and no remote. It’s a hunter fan. Not sure of the model right now. The rating for the fan is 40 watt lights. If I flip the switch multiple times. 3 to 4 it comes on and stays on. It acts the same no matter how many bulbs are in it. And both the fan and light are controlled by the switch.

Comment: Do you have some incandescents so you can verify this does *not* happen with them?  Do you have any other fixture that accepts candelabra-bases so you can verify the LED bulbs are ok?

Comment: It didn’t happen before with the cheap LEDs- they would just flicker some. And it didn’t happen with the bulbs before the LEDs. Which were halogen bulbs I believe. I don’t, it’s the only one in the house.